# Is there a wordpress plugin for the functionality found in this site?

Tags: wordpress

I was hoping to design a website with some of the functionality found in this site: https://hsf.net

Specifically, I would like to replicate the functionality of the tab organizer found on the middle of the home page.  I will attach a screen shot of what I am referring to in this post. The screen shot can be found with this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHZlO.png

I wanted to add this to add something like this to my own website(that i am currently developing) and was hoping someone knew how to get this from a wordpress plugin.  I really like the functionality and the look and feel that it provides.  If someone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for advice on third party resources on SO is not well-liked; read the FAQ on how to best ask questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

And it's a simple matter to look at the page source of the site; you will see that that tab functions are a very standard jQuery tabs arrangement. See http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

There may be a WordPress plugin for tabs; check https://wordpress.org/plugins/